# Windows Audio service can't be started after Blue Screen of Death, how can I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update, bsod

I am using Windows 10, and today (2021-01-28) I got a BSoD, the computer then rebooted automatically, and after reboot, sound, microphone and camera weren't working on the system;

Windows Defender disappeared, and I couldn't run `cmd` as admin (my account is the only account and it's an administrator account).

The last update was indeed installed today as shown by the update history:

```
Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Windows Defender Antivirus - Update KB2267602 (Version 1.329.3006.0)
```

Device manager showed that all device drivers were detected and up to date, I went to safe mode and ran: `sfc /scannow`

It found and repaired corrupt files, I then went back into normal mode, managed to launch `cmd` as admin with: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>>>type `cmd`>><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, ran `sfc /scannow` again, and it did not find any other problems.

Windows Audio service couldn't be started even if I tried to start it in `services.msc` it gave me:

```
Error 0x80070005: Access is denied.
```

I have a restore point created 1 week ago. Is this the only option? How can I uninstall this last KB update?

I am sadly no expert, sorry If the question is vague, I could give more information.

Any help is appreciated. Even if it's just teaching how to get thte log of the BSoD.

Comment: Download the Manufacturer's Driver Update App, install it and update all Drivers including BIOS and Chipset (if there is a Chipset driver on your computer).

Comment: I don't think you need to perform a system restore, I believe all your problems caused by BSoD have already been fixed by sfc, you can't start Windows Audio is because your sound card driver is generic rather than the optimal driver, install the optimal drive and your issue will be fixed.